# Wordpress Site Admin can't publish <iframe>s on multsite network

Tags: wordpress, iframe, embed, multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite network. I've found that if you're not a Network Admin, Site Admins cannot publish `<iframe>s` or `<script>` tags.

What I've tried:

- Added the `unfiltered_html` capability to the Admin role
- Added `iframe` to the global `$allowedtags`
- Added `iframe` to the `extended_valid_elements` using the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter

I've read around a lot, and I know there's an Iframe plugin, but It would really be best to allow my users to copy and paste Iframes from YouTube, etc.

Any insight is much appreciated!

**EDIT: full code below**

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role('administrator');
    $role->add_cap('unfiltered_html');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');



public function add_tags()
{
    global $allowedtags;
    $allowedtags['iframe'] = [
        'src'               => [],
        'width'             => [],
        'height'            => [],
        'frameborder'       => [],
        'style'             => [],
        'allowfullscreen'   => []
    ];
}
add_action('init', 'add_tags');



public function add_mce_tags($options) {
    // Comma separated string of extended tags
    $ext = 'iframe[align|longdesc|name|width|height|frameborder|scrolling|marginheight|marginwidth|src]';

    if (isset($options['extended_valid_elements'])) {
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    // maybe; set tiny paramter verify_html
    // $options['verify_html'] = false;
    return $options;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_mce_tags');
```

Comment: Can you post the code you used to give `unfiltered_html` back to admins?

Comment: @Xhynk Added full code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue using shortcode. If you not found needed solution.

Something like that

```
add_shortcode('book', array('iframe_shortcode', 'shortcode')); class iframe_shortcode {
    function shortcode($atts, $content=null) {
          extract(shortcode_atts(array(
               'url'      => '',
               'scrolling'      => 'yes',
               'width'      => '680',
               'height'      => '850',
               'frameborder'      => '0',
               'marginheight'      => '0',
          ), $atts));
          if (empty($url)) return '<!-- Iframe: You did not enter a valid URL -->';
     return '<iframe src="'.$url.'" title="" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'" scrolling="'.$scrolling.'" frameborder="'.$frameborder.'" marginheight="'.$marginheight.'"><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank">'.$url.'</a></iframe>';
    } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, especially since it provides an alternative (and viable) solution to the question. As a note, I'd double check your code (it's a bit easier in an IDE if you aren't using one) - as the shortcode you've posted would require OP to use `[book url="https://example.com/"]` instead of something more semantic like `[iframe url="https://example.com/"]` - and be sure to check your formatting and indenting once you submit your answer, to make sure it's easy to parse through and read. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Code was just an example and for sure should be changed or customized to specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

`admin` isn't a valid default role, I believe you're looking for [`administrator`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Administrator). It's also considered a good practice to make sure your `$role` object is actually defined (though in this case it shouldn't be an issue), this should get you up and running:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    if( $role = get_role( 'administrator' ) ){
        $role->add_cap('unfiltered_html');
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps' );
```

Comment: Good catch. I actually was using a plugin to do it before, still with no luck.

Comment: `unfiltered_html` seems to be deprecated anyways.