# Create youtube embed code for wordpress with customized parameters

Tags: wordpress, youtube, embed, video-embedding

I want to get a youtube video into a blog post and it should have these features:

start & end time,
autoplay, 
loop, 
no controls showing

I tried to customize the code myself but only the start and end time worked the rest didn't.

Comment: It's better if you show the code you're trying, this way it's easier to tell what you're doing wrong... You can **[edit]** your question to add details.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the same shortcode and add you own parameters.

[Wordpress Site Admin can't publish <iframe>s on multsite network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52172991/wordpress-site-admin-cant-publish-iframes-on-multsite-network/52173522#52173522)